# magento 2 both forntend and admin isbroken

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Magento admin and frontend is broken.

I tried to run the commands setup:upgrade, di:compile, static-content:deploy -f but website is still broken.

Comment: What error message are you getting?